# Docker nfs4 mount on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nfs

I am stuck accessing a nfs4 share inside a docker container, running on Elastic Beanstalk.

[Netshare](http://netshare.containx.io/docs/nfs) is up and running on the EC2 instance running the Docker container. Mounting the nfs share manually on the instance works, I can access the share on the EC2 instance without problems.

However, when I run a container, trying to mount a nfs4 volume, the files are not appearing inside the container.

I do this. First, start the netshare daemon on the Docker host:

```
sudo ./docker-volume-netshare nfs
INFO[0000] == docker-volume-netshare :: Version: 0.18 - Built: 2016-05-27T20:14:07-07:00 == 
INFO[0000] Starting NFS Version 4 :: options: ''
```

Then, on the Docker host, start the docker container. Use `-v` to create a volume mounting the nfs4 share:

```
sudo docker run --volume-driver=nfs -v ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/home/ec2-user/nfs-share/templates:/home/ec2-user/xxx -ti aws_beanstalk/current-app /bin/bash
root@0a0c3de8a97e:/usr/src/app#
```

That worked, according to the netshare daemon:

```
INFO[0353] Mounting NFS volume ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/nfs-share/templates on /var/lib/docker-volumes/netshare/nfs/ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/home/ec2-user/nfs-share/templates
```

So I try listing the contents of `/home/ec2-user/xxx` inside the newly launched container - but its empty?!

```
root@0a0c3de8a97e:/usr/src/app# ls /home/ec2-user/xxx/
root@0a0c3de8a97e:/usr/src/app#
```

Strangely enough, the nfs volume has been mounted correctly on the host:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ sudo ls -lh /var/lib/docker-volumes/netshare/nfs/ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/home/ec2-user/nfs-share/templates | head -3
total 924K
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4,0K 29. Dez 14:12 file1
drwxr-xr-x 4 ec2-user ec2-user 4,0K  9. Mai 17:20 file2
```

Could this be a permission problem? Both the nfs server and client are using the `ec2-user` user/group. The docker container is running as `root`.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

If i start the container in `--privileged` mode, mounting the nfs share directly inside the container becomes possible:

```
sudo docker run --privileged -it aws_beanstalk/current-app /bin/bash
mount -t nfs4 ec2-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/nfs-share/templates /mnt/
ls -lh /mnt | head -3
total 924K
drwxr-xr-x 5 500 500 4.0K Dec 29 14:12 file1
drwxr-xr-x 4 500 500 4.0K May  9 17:20 file2
```

Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem, because Elastic Beanstalk does not allow privileged containers (unlike ECS).

**UPDATE 2**

Here's another workaround:

1. mount the nfs share on the host into `/target`
2. restart docker on the host
3. run container `docker run -it -v /target:/mnt image /bin/bash`

`/mnt` is now populated as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@sebastian's "UPDATE 2" got me on the right track (thanks @sebastian).

But for others who may reach this question via Google like I did, here's exactly how I was able to automatically mount an EFS (NFSv4) file system on Elastic Beanstalk and make it available to containers.

Add this `.config` file:

```
# .ebextensions/01-efs-mount.config
commands:
  01umount:
    command: umount /mnt/efs
    ignoreErrors: true
  02mkdir:
    command: mkdir /mnt/efs
    ignoreErrors: true
  03mount:
    command: mount -t nfs4 -o vers=4.1 $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone).EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID.efs.AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com:/ /mnt/efs
  04restart-docker:
    command: service docker stop && service docker start
  05restart-ecs:
    command: docker start ecs-agent
```

Then `eb deploy`. After the deploy finishes, SSH to your EB EC2 instance and verify that it worked:

```
ssh ec2-user@YOUR_INSTANCE_IP
ls -la /mnt/efs
```

You should see the files in your EFS filesystem. However, you still need to verify that the mount is readable and writable within containers.

```
sudo docker run -v /mnt/efs:/nfs debian:jessie ls -la /nfs
```

You should see the same file list.

```
sudo docker run -v /mnt/efs:/nfs debian:jessie touch /nfs/hello
sudo docker run -v /mnt/efs:/nfs debian:jessie ls -la /nfs
```

You should see the file list plus the new `hello` file.

```
ls -la /mnt/efs
```

You should see the `hello` file outside of the container as well.

Finally, here's how you use `-v /mnt/efs:/nfs` in your `Dockerrun.aws.json`.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "image": "AWS_ID.dkr.ecr.AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/myimage:latest",
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "containerPath": "/nfs",
          "sourceVolume": "efs"
        }
      ],
      "name": "myimage"
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [
    {
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/mnt/efs"
      },
      "name": "efs"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great for me. Only thing I didn't understand was the line in your .config: 05restart-ecs:
    command: docker start ecs-agent
What is "ecs-agent"

Comment: From https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent: "The Amazon ECS Container Agent is software developed for Amazon EC2 Container Service (Amazon ECS). It runs on container instances and starts containers on behalf of Amazon ECS."

Comment: Thanks markplindsay for adding the details, I didnt' take the time to write down everything.